# Form Select using Bootstrap in ABP

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have been having a problem with a form select which allows users to make a selection on a modal edit.

here is the modal ui - a users may select a 'software type'.

[image]
The page renders without errors (according to chrome [devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/))

I get an error upon Saving (with or without changes)

I suspect it's some sort of type casting error where the service expects an int and i'm sending a string.  if that theory is right how do i proceed from here? 
the js file for the save button calls the service to do the save directly so i don't get a chance to anything server side.

Appreciate any ideas, Thanks for reading.

[image]

**CSHTML**
Here is my _cshtml file[image]

**Controller**
[image]

**_EditPracticeModal.js**
[image]

**Mvc\App_Data\Logs\Logs.txt**
[image]

Comment: "I suspect ... i'm sending a string" → You can check that in the Network tab.

Comment: thanks,I did inspected the network tab. but i'm unsure as to how and inspect the actual payload as it's encypted.  i'm but assuming i am sending a string or an incorrect value (e.g. 0 - key does not exist) .is there anything you can see in my code that should be corrected?  i'm really at a loss as to how to progress this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for failure is straightforward, You are sending the invalid value for `SoftwareType`, it could be `undefined`, `null` or an empty value if the datatype is int or similar. You can check this in the browser, you can refer the below screenshot.

[image: Chrome Developer tool]

You can also check your model for the valid `SoftwareType` value.

You should send `SoftwareTypeId` not `SoftwareType`in the request.

Comment: my request contains :{"Id":"3","Name":"32132","RegistrationNumber":"321321","SoftwareType":"1","Latitude":"0","Longitude":"0","Email1":"","Email2":"","Mobile1":"","Mobile2":"","Telephone1":"","PasswordContact":"","SpecialRequest":""}

Comment: Definitely check your model class and check for Software type member declaration. Check if there any data annotation or validation is there

Comment: So it is a valid index ( can be 1,2 or 3)

Comment: The Dto has:  [DisplayName("Software")]
        public SoftwareTypeDto SoftwareType { get; set; }
        public int? SoftwareTypeId { get; set; }    while the Entity has slightly different: [ForeignKey("SoftwareTypeId")]
        [DisplayName("Software")]
        public SoftwareType SoftwareType { get; set; }
        public int? SoftwareTypeId { get; set; }

Comment: @user703163 You should send it as `SoftwareTypeId`. `"1"` is clearly not a `SoftwareType` entity.

Comment: thank you, please add as answer and i will mark it as anwered